# Replacing an item in memcached without changing the expiration time

Tags: replace, memcached

I have several items on memcached that should expire 24h after the creation time. I need to update those items, while keeping the expiration time unchanged.

How can I do this? Apparently the replace function requires an expiration parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this type of control over expiry, you'll need to carry the expiration time of the stored item alongside the item itself.

The way this is typically accomplished is through a serializing layer.  Entries written to memcached are stored as the entry itself and a timestamp.  When the entry is deserialized, the timestamp is checked, and if its expired, the read entry is discarded and treated as a cache miss.

```
[ entry, expiresAt ]
```

The TTL on the raw memcached entries is typically set to infinity and entries are only expunged from the cache manually, or via the [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) policy.

In the memcached FAQ, there is a section on [preventing stampeding requests](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks#Avoiding_stampeding_herd) that touches on this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store when the value was cached, along with its original timeout value. Here's a Python implementation:

```py
class ExpiringCache(BaseCache):
    """A cache that allows you to update values without changing when the
    data will expire. We do this by storing when the value was
    inserted in the cache and decrementing the timeout when we update.

    """
    def get(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        raw_value = super(ExpiringCache, self).get(key, *args, **kwargs)

        # we get None on a cache miss, but otherwise it's a 3-tuple
        if raw_value is None:
            return None

        value, start_time, timeout = raw_value
        return value

    def set(self, key, value, *args, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs.get('timeout')

        raw_value = (value, now(), timeout)
        super(ExpiringCache, self).set(key, raw_value, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, key, value, timeout=None):
        """If this value is still in the cache, update it but reduce the
        timeout. If it's not present, just set it.

        """
        raw_value = super(ExpiringCache, self).get(key)

        if raw_value is None:
            self.set(key, value, timeout=timeout)
            return

        original_value, start_time, original_timeout = raw_value

        if not original_timeout:
            # we are caching without a timeout, so just set the new value
            self.set(key, value, timeout=original_timeout)
            return

        elapsed_time = (now() - start_time).total_seconds()
        remaining_timeout = timeout - elapsed_time

        if remaining_timeout > 0:
            self.set(key, value, timeout=remaining_timeout)
```